# Estimations for the number of prime factors, counted with multiplicity (elementary combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

If $N_k(x):=\ \mid\{n\leq x : \Omega(n)=k\}\mid$, where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors (counted with multiplicity) in $n$, I am trying to reason a crude under-estimate for large $k$ and large $x$. I wonder whether someone could tell whether the following is a reasonable statement:

Since $(p_{\ 2})^{101}<10^{40}$ (the $n$th prime is shown here as $p_{\ n}$), a crude under-estimation for $N_{101}(10^{40})$ may be given as follows:

If the $n$th primorial is denoted $\#_n$, is is easy to find that $$10^{40}-(p_{\ 1})^{89}\cdot \#_{12}>0>10^{40}-(p_{\ 1})^{88}\cdot \#_{13}$$

By iteration (trial and error!), it is similarly straightforward to find that $$10^{40}-(p_{\ 1})^{100}\cdot (p_{\ 362\ 896\ 183})^{1}>0>10^{40}-(p_{\ 1})^{100}\cdot (p_{\ 362\ 896\ 184})^{1}$$

It can therefore be said that $N_{101}(10^{40})>362\ 896\ 183+12!\ (=8.41897783\times10^{8})$.

Is it then reasonable to assume that $N_{101}(10^{40})>8.41897783\times10^{8}$, but of a similar order?

Comment: You have posted estimates for $N_k$ in other questions. What do those estimates tell you? Why don't you include links to your other questions --- it would make life easier for people trying to help you.

Comment: Yes, the estimate that I get is approximately of the same order as stated here - (approximately 4 times the number given, in fact). I am just posting this to see whether this line of reasoning is correct.